# Azure Advisor - Virtual Machine Scale Sets

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-advisor

Out of the box, **Azure Advisor** includes Cost recommendations for the resource type of **Virtual Machines**, based on resource utilization.

If I look at them under our subscription they have the following information:

[image]

Is there any way to get similar advisory for the **Virtual Machine Scale Set** resource type? Is there any included out of the box?

Or if I want to get average resource consumption, of let's say CPU percentage of all **or** individual Virtual Machine instances inside of a Virtual Machine Scale set, to be able to aid in the decision if the SKU of the Virtual Machine Scale Set is appropriate, I need to make a query for this inside of **Monitor Logs** or similar?

Could one create their own custom made advisories (inside of **Azure Advisor**, if not - anywhere else?), to get this functionaltiy in place (if it isn't already provided)?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Comment: where did you navigate to in order to see the additional capacity columns like CPU utilization, network and memory? I dont see those in azure advisor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to get similar advisory for the Virtual Machine Scale Set resource type? Is there any included out of the box?

As per the Azure Advisor [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/advisor/advisor-overview#what-resources-does-advisor-provide-recommendations-for), Advisor provides recommendations for the following resource types:

Application Gateway, App Services, availability sets, Azure Cache, Azure Data Factory, Azure Database for MySQL, Azure Database for PostgreSQL, Azure Database for MariaDB, Azure ExpressRoute, Azure Cosmos DB, Azure public IP addresses, Azure Synapse Analytics, SQL servers, storage accounts, Traffic Manager profiles, and Virtual machines.

Although Azure Advisor also includes your recommendations from Azure Security Center which may include recommendations for additional resource types, this list does not cover cost recommendations for VMSS as of today, AFAIK.

> I need to make a query for this inside of Monitor Logs or similar?

To monitor your Virtual machine Scale sets, you can leverage [Azure Monitor](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/virtual-machine-scale-set-insights-from-azure-monitor/). The [performance views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-performance#view-performance-directly-from-an-azure-virtual-machine-scale-set) in the VM Insights feature are powered using log analytics queries, offering “Top N”, aggregate, and list views to quickly find outliers or issues in your scale set based on guest level metrics for CPU, available memory, bytes sent and received, and logical disk space used.

You can also deploy the Azure Monitor [Application Insights Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-vm-vmss-apps) on Azure virtual machine scale sets to enable monitoring for your .NET or Java based web applications and get all the benefits of using Application Insights without modifying your code.

> Could one create their own custom made advisories (inside of Azure Advisor, if not - anywhere else?), to get this functionaltiy in place (if it isn't already provided)?

Nope, that is not doable as of today. Azure Advisor is a managed offering that analyzes your resource configuration and usage telemetry and then recommends solutions that can help you optimize your Azure resources. Feel free to share your feedback and ideas [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/919474-azure-advisor) for the Advisor team to evaluate and prioritize.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer Bhargavi, I appreciate it!